# FastCGI or PSGI Interface to NGINX in 2021

Tags: perl, nginx, uwsgi, fastcgi, starman

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68331091/compiling-perl-for-faster-fastcgi-operation) I asked has resulted in me exploring directly interfacing my FastCGI script to NGINX, rather than using a reverse proxy to Apache. I successfully modified my FastCGI script to run as a daemon using some code I found online:

```
my $s = FCGI::OpenSocket(':9000',20);
my $request = FCGI::Request( \*STDIN, \*STDOUT, \*STDERR, \%ENV, $s);

# Remaining code stays just as it does when using with Apache's mod_fcgid
while($request->Accept() >= 0) {
     # Call core app subroutines.
}
```

It works, but near as I can tell this has a distinct disadvantage over mod_fcgid: I have one process running which will handle one request at a time and if that process dies, there's nothing to start it back up. There are references on Stack Overflow to code that properly spun off workers, but the sites referenced inevitably seem to have gone offline, much like FastCGI's own site.

So, I'm trying to figure out what I need to add and also -- pardon the pun -- figure out if I need to take a fork in this road. Here are the options that I am trying to consider, if I understand my issues correctly:

1. Directly implement some sort of forking mechanism, ideally it seems like it should (1) toss off the request to a process/thread/worker -- perhaps one that can stay alive for multiple requests -- and move on to being ready for the next request and (2) be independent enough from the workers that if something goes wrong with a worker, it doesn't bring down the whole system until I catch it and restart the main process (e.g. autorestart processes). If this can be done simply and reliably, this seems to have a huge appeal since the code already works with FastCGI.
2. Give up on direct FastCGI and convert to PSGI and use an application server to handle these things. Given that I'm using Perl, I'd guess Starman is the logical option, although I've been reading on uwsgi's PSGI support and it sounds almost ideal in "tyrant Emperor" mode, where it could run processes with different privileges, auto restart missing processes, etc.

Option 1 seems intriguing since it requires the least modification to my existing code and a FastCGI script started up without FastCGI still works like a normal CGI script. (I'm not running this code under FastCGI when it is used by sites that are very low traffic).

Option 2, though, feels like it might be more "modern." At least PSGI documentation seems to still be online, for example, and using Starman or uwsgi seem like they take care of the background stuff I need probably better than I would cooking up my own system. Downside: I'd need two startup scripts for my code: one to be used by the PSGI enabled sites and one for sites still running in CGI.

**Update:** Continuing to explore option 1, I read through [this tutorial on Perl `fork()`](https://perlmaven.com/fork#:%7E:text=Using%20fork%20in%20Perl%20to%20spread%20load%20to,system%20this%20can%20be%20done%20using%20fork%20%28%29) which seems somewhat relevant. Would using `fork` to break off each FastCGI request be a good approach if I go with option 1? I assume I'd be at risk of fork bombing, although if I kept track of the number of forks and issued `wait() if ($forks > 10);` perhaps that would be a safe approach? (Or perhaps using `Parallel::ForkManager` to do that process watching.) Or would it be safer and/or more efficient using something like `Thread::Queue` and passing FastCGI request objects to a set a threads that are reliably already established? There seem to be plenty of pitfalls I might overlook, which then returns me to whether I should opt for Option 2.

Comment: Did you consider using `spawn-fcgi` or `multiwatch`?

Comment: @jo-37 I've looked a little into `spawn-fcgi` but haven't gotten it successfully working yet. I'll check out `multiwatch`.

Comment: I'm still exploring these different options to figure out which one is most efficient. I did create a PSGI version of my main script and ran it via Starman. The individual request execution speed is slower than a FastCGI interface to NGINX (more akin to reverse proxying to Apache), but since my FastCGI interface can only take one request at a time, Starman/PSGI was significantly faster if I hit it with a bunch of concurrent requests. I'm still trying to exploring how to create a multithreaded FastCGI arrangement (like mod_fcgid) with NGINX, which seems like it would be the fastest option.